# Using Laravel for Service Workers?

Tags: php, laravel, service-worker

I am learning service workers from Udacity and they are using a nodejs backend to work on service workers. Is there any way to use the same in Laravel framework. I have tried it once, but I don't know how to store the compiled html, css and js on cache. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use nodejs in order to work with a service worker. Just register the worker somewhere in `app.js` and use the `install` and `fetch` event in a seperate file (e.g. `sw.js`) to intervene in Http requests with:

```
// app.js
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js', {
    scope: './'
});

// sw.js
// fetch
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```